# How to build svnwcrev

Tags: make, subversion

I'm having a bad time building [svnwcrew](http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/), and as the readme file says: "There is no sophisticated installation procedure for this small utility."...

I modified the config.mk file setting the APR_INCLUDE as the readme says, and when I run **make**:

> http://pastebin.com/NE1nevek

any suggestion to build this tool?
Thanks!

Comment: Only if you post the actual error messages that appeared.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NE1nevek

Comment: The developer needs to update his code for more recent compilers/standard C++ libraries.

Comment: I added a #include <cstddef> to the SVNcRev.h as a guy at the Arch irc pointed out, now it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from **slm** I had to do the following to get the latest source from tigress to compile on Ubuntu 15.10

```
wget http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/files/documents/3444/44067/svnwcrev-1.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf svnwcrev-1.0.tar.gz 
apt-get install libapr1-dev libsvn-dev
cd svnwcrev-1.0
```

This provided the headers referred to in the config.mk file, then after renaming config_mk.template to config.mk.

I then had to add the following at line 33 of src/SVNWcRev.cpp

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

This fixed a compiler error where Expansion and ptrdiff_t were undefined.

I also had to modify the Makefile to include missing libraries and disable a warning. The changed lines are listed here:

```
...
CPPFLAGS=-I$(SUBVERSION_INCLUDE) -I$(APR_INCLUDE) -Wno-deprecated-declarations
...
LDLIBS=-lpthread -L$(LIBRARIES) -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_wc-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lapr-1
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I can only offer you how I've done this on **CentOS** & **Fedora** Linux distros. I know a co-worker who got it to build on `Ubuntu` as well but I'm not familiar with all the steps they took to accomplish this.

For myself I used the following steps.

First I needed to make a change to line # 150 in `SVNWcRev.cpp`.

```
# before: 
#define USE_TIME_NOW    -2  // 0 and -1 might already be significant.

# after:
#define USE_TIME_NOW    apr_time_now()  // 0 and -1 might already be significant.
```

**NOTE:** The details for the `apr_time_now()` function were on this [page](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__apr__time.html).

This function returns the current time. Also that page detailed the function `apr_time_exp_lt()`. In the file `SVNWcRev.cpp` there is a function `InsertDate()` that is called with several arguments including `USE_TIME_NOW`. This argument along with a newly constructed `apr_time_exp_t` object are passed to the `apr` function, `apr_time_exp_lt()`. With the original value of **-2**, this function was returning 12/31/1969 (1/1/1970 - 2usecs).

My co-workers and I seemed to think that this might have been correct behavior on a different platform, or possibly a older version of the `apr` library was implemented differently where that used to work. I used `apr` version 1.4.5 to build `svnwcrev`.

Changing to the function `apr_time_now()` fixed the issue.

**Installation & Setup**

`svnwcrev` is a implementation of the `subwcrev.exe` tool provided by `TortoiseSVN`, [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html). I found `svnwcrev` [here](http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/). I downloaded `svnwcrev` like so:

```
% svn checkout http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/svn/svnwcrev/trunk svnwcrev --username guest
```

**NOTE:** I got the following version of svnwcrev.

```
% svn info
Path: .
URL: http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/svn/svnwcrev/trunk
Repository Root: http://svnwcrev.tigris.org/svn/svnwcrev
Repository UUID: 4d73e863-0307-0410-bf4f-fe65b2d002b6
Revision: 10
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: mailman
Last Changed Rev: 10
Last Changed Date: 2011-05-26 05:05:03 -0400 (Thu, 26 May 2011)
```

Once downloaded I made the following changes.

**1.** created a `config.mk` file:

```
% cp config_mk.template config.mk
```

**2.** changed `config.mk` so that it looked like this:

```
SUBVERSION_INCLUDE=/usr/include/subversion-1
APR_INCLUDE=/usr/include/apr-1
LIBRARIES=/usr/lib
```

**3.** installed the `apr-devel` and `subversion-devel` RPMs.

**4.** compiled `svnwcrev` like so:

```
% make
```

Comment: I don't have 
`before: #define USE_TIME_NOW    -2  // 0 and -1 might already be significant.` at line # 151

Comment: that line isn't a literal "before: that's what the line looked like before and after I changed it. The after is what it should look like after.

Comment: BTW, try the steps I outlined above, I just double checked and they worked fine on my Fedora & CentOS systems.